# API images not rendering

Tags: javascript, json, image

I am trying to fetch some text and images from local JSON file. The text is coming but the images in not.

It is in html file. Please help me.

This is the result:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

[image: The result is in React]

[image: The result in html]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your images over `https` and not `http`

```
http://bcdn.newshunt.com/cmd...
```

should be

```
https://bcdn.newshunt.com/cmd...
```

see images

> no https
> [image]

> with https
> [image]